# Channel API overkill?

Tags: google-app-engine, overriding, channel-api

Hi I am currently using channel API for my project. My client is  a signage player which receives data from app engine server only when user changes a media content. Appengine sends data to client only ones or twice a day. Do you think channel api is a over kill for this? what are some other alternatives?

Comment: How many clients will be connected? Per https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas?hl=en#Channel the free quota is 200 channel-hours/day, so if you have no more than 8 clients connected you'll be within the free quota -- no "overkill". Even beyond that, per  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing , there'

Answer (score 6):

Overall, I'd think not. How many clients will be connected?

Per https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas?hl=en#Channel the free quota is 200 channel-hours/day, so if you have no more than 8 clients connected you'll be within the free quota -- no "overkill".

Even beyond that, per  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing , there's "no additional charge" beyond the computational resources keeping the channel open entails -- I don't have exact numbers but I don't think those resources would be "overkill" compared with alternatives such as reasonably frequent polling by the clients.

Comment: Please be aware that you must disclose affiliation where needed. Please read [how to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion), then edit your answer to include proper disclosure. Failure to do so will result in your post being deleted, along with other consequences.

Answer (score 2):

According to the Channel API documentation (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/features/#channel), "The Channel API creates a persistent connection between an application and its users, allowing the application to send real time messages without the use of polling.". IMHO, yours might not the best use case for it.

You may want to take a look into the TaskQueue API (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/features/#taskqueue) as an alternative of sending data from AppEngine to the client.